# How can I get more than 4GB for my macOS application?

Tags: c, macos

I am coding in C using Xcode on a MacBook.

The following program runs fine with n=1073741823 and gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x200007ffc), if I increase the value of n by 1.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define n 1073741823

int array[n];

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) 
{
   printf("\n Size of array = %lu\n", (unsigned long) n*sizeof(int));
   array[n-1] = 1;
   return 0;
}
```

With the lower value of n, the size of the array is just below 4GB, and incrementing n by 1 pushes the size over 4GB and causes the runtime error.

I am using Xcode 15.0.1 on a 64GB MacBook Pro with Sonoma 14.0.

I cannot imagine that Apple wants to limit me to 4GB, and I cannot find any reference to such a limit (or to an option to increase memory size).

What must I do to be able to use 20GB or more in my code?

Comment: What happens if you dynamically allocate the array?

Comment: "*I cannot imagine that Apple wants to limit me to 4GB*" -- you are evidently lacking in imagination, then. I don't know whether it is an intentional or acknowledged design constraint that is getting in your way here, but I have no trouble at all imagining that it *could* be.  Note also that there is a major difference between limiting you to 4GB total and limiting you to 4GB for any single object.

Comment: That's a lot of data to store in the data segment of your executable.

Comment: Possibly a 'policy' to achieve better memory management.   Dynamic allocation or a memory mapped file might allow the OS to better manage the memory demands of your application and that if others perhaps.

Comment: Which compiler? What cpu chip? I'd disassemble the code. Then, do asm inst single stepping in the debugger. I'd look at the memory map. Also, does the corresponding `malloc` version work? It'd be difficult for the OS to limit in this way. More likely a compiler bug? Because such access is limited to the _entire_ program: code + libs + data + stack. So, you're 1073741823 --> 0x3FFFFFFF `int` values. This is 0xFFFFFFFC bytes. So, one more is 0x100000000 bytes (i.e. offset). **But**, you're already over the 4GB limit because of code size, so not an OS trap like stack limit.

Comment: Try with `malloc()`. If you have 4GB in your data segment and a 100MB/s disk, your app is always going to take 40s to even start and appear. I guess Apple might not like looking slow.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I would think there _would_ be a long load time _if_ we had `int array[n] = { 1, 2, 3 };` as it would go into the `.data` section. But, as OP has it, it would go into the `.bss` section. I'm not familiar with the vagaries of macos, as under linux (or even *BSD), the `.bss` loading (e.g. `memset`) would take little time. So, what is special about macos for this?

Comment: @CraigEstey Yes, I agree. I was merely suggesting that if the data are not initialised to any particular value, OP might as well use `malloc()` to get uninitialised space, but if the data do need to be initialised at compile time, there would be a long startup time to load 4GB from disk. Maybe I didn't express that too well.

Comment: To OP: Again, as Mark (and I) suggested, try using `malloc`. The overhead of the [indirect] pointer is negligible with a 20GB array compared to the overhead of cache misses, etc. Also, it's more flexible as you can grow/shrink the size and you're not hamstrung as you would be with a fixed size (e.g. you specify 20GB but for a single given invocation, you need 21GB).

Comment: Are you on Intel or Apple Silicon? On my M1 with Xcode 15.0.1 and Sonoma 14.1, I am oddly getting nasty errors for `n` in 521720597 to 1073741823, about no such dynamic library to load! For 1073741824 and above, I am getting just a bus error.

Comment: thanks for all you suggestions. here are my responses:
1) there was no problem with the previous version of XCode; the problems started after updating to XCode 15
2) my mac has intel silicon
3) using malloc seems to work fine
4) there is no noticeable loading delay
5) the problem also occurs if i have several large arrays, when their total memory requirement exceeds 4GB, so it's not a single-object problem. 
6) i wanted to avoid malloc, because the arrays are in fact three-dimensional array[nx][ny][nz], so i would have to figure out how to emulate them using malloc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a clang thing and not an Apple thing. On a BSD system with clang 13.0.0, I get:

```
ld: error: Insanely large symbol size for object (in GOT) array
```

gcc seems to have no issue with 4GB and larger BSS arrays. Apple's clang (which is a more recent version of clang, 15.0.0) apparently is not issuing error messages in this regard when it should. Apple may have it's own modified `ld`.

You should be using `malloc()` for large arrays. Even much smaller large arrays. Putting that array in the BSS requires, per the C standard, that it all be initialized to zeros, or at least logically appear to be zeros (by initializing only on demand), which you likely don't need. `malloc()` doesn't initialize the memory.

Answer (score 0):

I have converted all my large arrays to [`malloc()`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/stdlib.h/malloc) and the size restriction is no longer affecting me.

The replacement code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define n 1073741823

int* array;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) 
{
   array = (int *) malloc(n*sizeof(int));
   return 0;
}
```

ChatGPT showed me how to generate 3D arrays, but the preceding code is not from ChatGPT.

Comment: malloc means you switch from stack memory to heap memory. Not surprising that the stack memory limit doesn't affect you anymore. And please add the code which you used to fix the problem.

Comment: @BDL He wasn't using stack memory before. He was using BSS memory. That is neither heap nor stack.

Comment: @Mark Adler I was puzzled by that ...